# d3js - On duplicating SVG element, resulting wrong output

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I created a `svg` graphics using `d3js`. and i have a scenario to show the same graphics on click on the popup, so i am duplicating with another `div` element on `click` of the existing `svg` element.

it works. but the result is wrong. the appending new svg is pre-pending and being as first element instead of last.

on my first element i have opacity as `0.5' in the duplicated element i have the`opacity:1`, and the color changing to "blue" but it not work in correct way. here is my code :

```
var w = 100;
var h = 100;
var padding = 5;

var svg = d3.select('#svg1').append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: w,
        height: h
    });

svg.append('rect')
    .attr({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        fill: 'red'
    });

var little = svg.selectAll('rect.small')
    .data(d3.range(9));



little.enter().append('rect')
    .attr({
        width: w / 3 - padding * 2,
        height: h / 3 - padding * 2,
        fill: 'grey',
        x: function(d) { return d % 3 * (w / 3) + padding; },
        y: function(d) { return ~~(d / 3) * (h / 3) + padding; }
    });

var group = svg.append("svg:g").attr("id", "textInfo")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ w/2+","+h/2+")");

var text = group.append("text").text("Testing")
    .attr("class", "inform")
    .style({
    "text-anchor" : "middle",
    "fill" : "yellow",
    "opacity" : 0.5
});

function addAnother() {
    var content = d3.select("#svg1").html();
    var div = d3.select('#svg2').html(content);
    //adding text

    d3.select('.inform').style({
        "fill" : "blue",
        "opacity" : 1
    })
}

svg.on('click', addAnother);
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6u9x/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element is properly appended, but when you select the elements with the *inform* class, you actually end up selecting and changing the first element instead.

If you want to alter the style of the second element(the appended one), you have to change the selector from:

```
d3.select('.inform').style({
    "fill" : "blue",
    "opacity" : 1
})
```

to:

```
d3.select('#svg2 .inform').style({
    "fill" : "blue",
    "opacity" : 1
})
```